# I need to pass date/time dynamically to a JQuery widget. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am writing a script that utilizes the [`datetimepicker`](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) widget, which is an extension of JQuery's [`datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) widget. The widget is applied dynamically to a generated list of events via this code:

```
$(function() {
    $( 'input[id^="event_"]' ).datetimepicker({
        stepMinute: 15  
    });
});
```

The date/time can be set via the following option:

```
// where x is the dynamic ID of the row
var dtpicker = $( '#event_x' );
dtpicker.datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()) );
```

Here is how the rows are generated:

```
if($results != false){
    foreach($results as $event){
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"" . $event['id'] . "\" value=\"" . $event['name'] . "\" /></td>\n";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"event_" . $event['id'] . "\" value=\"" . $event['date'] . "\" /></td>\n";
        echo "<td>Save stuff here?</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    unset($event);
}else{
    echo "<div>Error getting events</div>\n";
}
```

Basically I have to loop through the generated rows, pull the date from the appropriate field, convert it from a string to a `Date()` and put that into the option.

I think I am going to use the `.click()` function to accomplish this. So far this is what I have come up with:

```
$( 'input[id^="event_"]' ).click(function() {
    //input format: 2011-09-15 20:30:00
    var mainSplit = $(this).val().split(" ");
    var dateSplit = mainSplit[0].split("-");
    var timeSplit = mainSplit[1].split(":");

    //alert($(this).val());
});
```

Any pointers/suggestions/solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the format you're using in your rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the date string to JavaScript's date constructor, and it'll create a date for you:

```
var theDate = new Date('2011-09-15 20:30:00'); // returns a date object
```

Comment: Perfect. No need for splitting :)